# Generating URL using Autofield before model is saved

Tags: python, django, image, url

I'd like for my image urls to be /img/1 and /img/2, and I thought using the auto incremented  id assigned to every model would be perfect for this, so that every url would be different. The problem is that an instance of a model does not have an id before it is saved. This is an issue in the code below from models.py:

```
def update_filename(instance, filename):
    a = type(instance.id)
    if a is not int:
        a = 1
    else: 
        a = instance.id
    path = "img" + "/" + str(a) + ".jpg"
    return path

class User_Image(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=update_filename)
```

Any suggestions on how to fix this? The id of every instance when django saves the pic is None, so every image saves into my img directory as "None" or "None_1" and so on.

Comment: Look at this https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/12009

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. From the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField.upload_to):

> In most cases, this object will not have been saved to the database
>   yet, so if it uses the default AutoField, it might not yet have a
>   value for its primary key field.

I use function like this:

```
import uuid
def update_filename(instance, filename):
    """ Rename picture """

    extension = os.path.splitext(filename)[1]
    return 'img/%s%s' % (uuid.uuid4(), extension)
```

Comment: I was going to do that, but the problem is the url is extremely long then. Would making a directory for each user, such as img/user1/1291219.jpg be a lot of strain on the site? This way, I could cut the random generated number down to a couple digits, since no one would be uploading that many pics to my site from one account